# Running JBoss Tattletale on a Tomcat war file returns no output

Tags: java, tattletale

I want to run JBoss Tattletale on a war file that my team has developed and generate all available reports.

I downloaded Tattletale 1.1.2 final and unzipped the file into a directory in Windows 7.  I created a report folder and copied my war into the Tattletale folder.  Following the example at https://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/userguide/1.2/en-US/html_single/#running I typed the following at the command prompt:

```
C:\Workspaces\tattletale-1.1.2.Final>java -Xmx512m -jar tattletale.jar myapp.war report
```

When I run the command, there is no output, no error, and no report.

Here is the config file:

```
classloader=org.jboss.tattletale.reporting.classloader.JBossAS6ClassLoaderStructure
profiles=java5, java6, spring30
reports=*
```

What do I need to do to generate reports?  I also tried the noop classloader but the results were the same.

Comment: A tag with 0 followers will be tough to get your question exposure.. Are there any other related tags that you could add?

Comment: Thanks Trevor, that's great advice.  I just added 'Java', hopefully that will spark some interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Tattletale was not able to read my war.  It may be because it was created for Tomcat 7.

I exploded the war to a directory with the "jar xvf" command and reran the same command on that folder:

```
java -Xmx512m -jar tattletale.jar myapp report
```

This created all of the reports.  I was most interested in the "unused jar" report, and I can see that it is incorrectly reporting some jars as unused, but I have gotten past my initial hurdle.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is helpful. Although it didn't generate correct output for me :-(